# Convert a column header into index

Tags: pandas, indexing, header

I have a pandas.Data.Frame of the following type:

```
       Unnamed           AAPL           IMBX ...
          Date  Price  Volume  Price  Volume ...
0   1973-01-01   21.1    1882   55.6    2009 ...  
1   1973-01-02   21.3    1787   54.5    2001 ...
2   1973-01-03   22.5    1701   52.0    2186 ...
3   1973-01-04   21.1    1799   53.3    1999 ...
```

I would like to rearrange the dataframe such that I can use `Date` and the stock name (e.g. having a column 'Stock' with the corresponding data) as index for my data, i.e. transforming them in long format. How can I do this?

Comment: Check with stack

Comment: @YOBEN_S could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code should work for you

```
df = df.set_index(("Unnamed", "Date")).unstack().unstack(level=1)
```

For your dataframe,

```
data = [["1973-01-01", 21.1, 1882, 55.6, 2009 ],
        ["1973-01-02", 21.3, 1787, 54.5, 2001 ],
        ["1973-01-03", 22.5, 1701, 52.0, 2186 ],
        ["1973-01-04", 21.1, 1799, 53.3, 1999 ]]

columns = [ ("Unnamed", "Date"), ("AAPL", "Price"), 
            ("AAPL", "Volume"), ("IMBX", "Price"), ("IMBX", "Volume")]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns))
```

this produces

```
                    Price   Volume
     (Unnamed, Date)         
AAPL    1973-01-01  21.1    1882.0
        1973-01-02  21.3    1787.0
        1973-01-03  22.5    1701.0
        1973-01-04  21.1    1799.0
IMBX    1973-01-01  55.6    2009.0
        1973-01-02  54.5    2001.0
        1973-01-03  52.0    2186.0
        1973-01-04  53.3    1999.0
```

If you want to have the date appear first in the index, you can swap multiindex levels with swaplevel and sort index for the resulting dataframe to look nice:

```
df = df.swaplevel().sort_index()
```

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for. Very elegant solution, thanks!